# trigger to count records for particular job id

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 2 objects contact & job and 1 site.in the site i have 3 fields job id, source(pick list :A & B) and name.if in the site someone will insert a particular job id and source as 'A' then that record is saving under Contact object. My requirement is to calculate number of records are coming for particular job id through source 'A' and through source 'B'. I want to write the trigger for that. i am not getting idea on how to write it.I am not getting how to count the number of records according to job id..

```
trigger SocialResponseCount on Contact (AFTER insert,BEFORE UPDATE) {

    list<Job__c> JList = new list<Job__c>();
    list<Contact> conList = new list<Contact>(); 

     Set<Id> conIds= new Set<Id>();
    contact con =new contact();

    for(contact c : Trigger.New){
    if (con.Source__c !=null  && con.Job_Id__c != null )
    system.debug('+++'+con.Id);
    {
       conList  =[select id,Name, Source__c ,Job_Id__c,Fb__c from contact where id=:conIds ]; 
        system.debug('test+++'+con.Id);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compiled this code? It will throw syntax error at if condition.

Comment: No its not throwing any syntax error ,can u suggest  any different method or syntax for this perticular  trigger @ Reshma.

Comment: Your check of the can values will always be null since you never populate those. Seems either you are very new or have just thrown some lines up randomly and are asking us to fix it. You will never enter the if block